# how can I sort the line of a file according to the special part of the line

Tags: regex, shell, sorting, awk

This is the file content (just a simplified example) which I want to sort:

```
  1 33      blabla_0_banana
  2 32333   lablab_4_apple
  3 1232312 hahaah_1_banana
  4 3342222 ohohoh_2_apple
```

And I want to sort the results with two requirement:

1. firstly  by the end word(eg: banana\apple)
2. secondly by the number between the two "_" symbols : _[number]_ (eg: 0\4\1\2)

this is the the result I wanted:

```
  4 3342222  ohohoh_2_apple
  2 32333    lablab_4_apple
  1 33       blabla_0_banana
  3 1232312  hahaah_1_banana
```

And finally, I want to delete the line with the second number >100000, this is also the result I wanted:

```
  2 32333    lablab_4_apple
  1 33       blabla_0_banana
```

How can I do this? Maybe with the command 'sort' , 'awk' or others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sort`:

```
sort -t_ -k3 -k2n file

4 3342222 ohohoh_2_apple
2 32333   lablab_4_apple
1 33      blabla_0_banana
3 1232312 hahaah_1_banana
```

To keep only rows with `2nd column < 100000` use `awk`:

```
awk '$2<100000' file | sort -t_ -k3 -k2n
2 32333   lablab_4_apple
1 33      blabla_0_banana
```

[Working Code Demo](http://ideone.com/ks24wt)

Comment: Thank you! It's amazing, but the awk command is not work, maybe there are some mistakes?  And could you explain more detail about how  the -t_, -k3, -k2n works?

Comment: `-t` option sets a delimiter as underscore. `-k3` sets 3rd column as first sort key and `-k2n` sets 2nd column as 2nd sort key in numerical order. Also check `man sort`

Comment: And how can I make `sort -t_ -k3 -k2n file | awk '$2<100000'` works? It seems not work :(

Comment: Check demo link in answer, it is working fine on ideone as well.

Comment: It's really weird! I almost copied you coded: `sort -t_ -k3 -k2n file.log | awk '$2<100000`. Maybe it's because the link demo used `stdin`, I used the file.log?
  `

Comment: You could also filter before sorting, which might be beneficial if the data sets are big (there's no point and some cost to sorting the rows that will be discarded).  Basic query optimization…

Comment: Good point @JonathanLeffler yes `awk '$2<100000' file | sort -t_ -k3 -k2n` will be better

Comment: Sure, you are right. But can you filter successfully in your computer? This command `sort -t_ -k3 -k2n file.log | awk '$2<100000` still not work :(

Comment: @springcc: It works for me on Mac OS X 10.11.5 with the native versions of `sort` and `awk`.  It also works with the GNU versions of `sort` (CoreUtils 8.24) and `awk` (4.1.3).  What platform are you on, and which version of which tools are you using?  You could try using `sort -t_ -k3,3 -k2,2n` instead; that limits the sort criteria to exactly the one field each time.  I get the same result with and without the comma clauses.  Obviously, we're only testing with your minimal sample data.

Comment: I'm working on `Scientific Linux release 6.5 (Carbon)` , with the version of awk: `GNU Awk 3.1.7`, the sort command is work successfully.

Comment: And when I use `awk '$2>[a number]' file`, there always print everything in the file, no matter how big the number is.  When I use `awk '$2<[a number]' file `   there always print nothing, no matter how small the number is....

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, It's from my stupid mistake: the first number in this question(1,2,3,4) is the line number displayed by the vim, I forgot this, so the right way is $1. Really sorry to you.@JonathanLeffler